# Aggregate in pymongo : match on day of week of date

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, dayofweek

I have a mongodb collection from which I'm trying to extract a subset where :

- Date is above a given date
- Date is either wednesday, thursday or friday

Here's my query so far :

```
for element in collection.aggregate( [
        { "$match": {
            "date" : {"$gt" : earliest_date, 
                      "$dayOfWeek" : { "$in": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] }
                    }
                    }
        },
        { "$sort": {"date": 1} },
        {
            "$group":
                { 
             ....
        }
        }]):
```

I get this error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown operator: $dayOfWeek
```

Can you help me out !
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to project week(day Of Week) from date field, before you can apply a filter on it.
["$dayOfWeek"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/) returns 1-7 values where 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday). So accordingly put condition on the projected field.

```
for element in collection.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "date": {"$gt": earliest_date}
    }
    },
    {"$project": {
        "date": "$date",
        "week": {"$dayOfWeek": "$date"},
        'anyOtherField': '$anyOtherField'
    }               
    },
    {"$match": {
        "week": {"$in": [4, 5, 6]}
    }
    {"$sort": {"date": 1}},
    {
        "$group":
            {
                ....
            }
    }]):
```